# Find and Regex on value in _variant_t

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am working with OLE Variants created externally and accessing them through `_variant_t`.

The Variants can contain text or numbers. I would like to be able to perform a search for arbitrary substrings in a similar fashion as `std::string::find`. But I am hoping to not have to convert to string values first. I have searched for a similar method for `_variant_t` but have not found one yet.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

In a similar vein, I'd like to also be able to perform Regex matching on the values stored in the Variants. How can this be done as well?

Comment: What does it even mean, to regex search on a number?

Comment: I mean its string representation. If a Variant held the LONG value of 1230009, for example, the string representation of it would be, "1230009" and perhaps I'd like to see if that representation included, "000". However, the Variant is just as likely to contain text in the form of BSTRs. I am looking for two things: a method to do a normal find() and also a method to do more complicated Regex matching. I am hoping that `_variant_t` has something like this already so that I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It doesn't. You need to do it manually. You can use VariantChangeType or VariantChangeTypeEx to convert to a BSTR. Afterwords, you can assign the BSTR to a std::wstring and maybe use any Unicode regex funcs, or you can use WideCharToMultiByte() to convert to a std::string (not directly) and then use your regex functions.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson Could you post an example as an answer?